# Complexity of std::set constructor from sorted elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Normally, constructing a `rb-tree` is `O(N*log(N))` time.

However, [initialization of `std::set` from sorted elements is linear time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set#Complexity).

How does that work? Is there a sorted-check before initialization? Or search from the right-most one?

Comment: Probably works for the same reason `std::set::insert` overload that takes a hint iterator works in constant time if the hint is actually correct. Just calling `insert` repeatedly with `end()` for hint would work in linear time on a sorted input.

Comment: I tried to clean up the link, but it looks like it breaks the text highlighting...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For me there's no highlighting in either version. Is that some Chrome thing?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Might be, I am using Chrome.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The highlight I used is made by `Link to text Fragment`, a chromium extension. And your highlight seems not work for my device..

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert an element into a set, the set has to first figure out where to insert it. If the first place it checks is the right place to insert it, then the complexity of that operation is O(1). If this somehow happens for *every* insertion operation, then the complexity for all such insertions is O(n).

So to implement this, the set merely has to start looking for where to insert the element at the place it *would* insert it if the sequence is sorted. So if the sequence happens to be sorted, the search time is O(1), and thus the insert time is O(n).

Comment: It should be noted that the complexity is amortized linear. The estimate does not include the complexity of rebalancing the tree as it gets populated (presumably, from one side).

Comment: But.. How to know whether a sequence is sorted? So for any sequences a check is required? (Though it's a linear check..)

Comment: @zjyhjqs: You don't need to. You just iterate, start-to-end, inserting each element in turn. And because you're keeping track of the last place you inserted something, if the next element would go there, then it takes O(1) time to find the right place to insert it.

Comment: @NicolBolas If the new element isn't the greatest, then a normal up-bottom search would be executed?